# Drag and Drop not working in Evolus Pencil

Tags: drag-and-drop, ubuntu-16.04, stencils, evolus-pencil

I've installed pencil using the .deb package and the Firefox plug-in but drag and drop is not working.Do someone got that problem? I'm using Firefox 50 on ubuntu-16.04

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but the following issue helped me.

https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/issues/856